# ANTLR how to create a "rest of it" token

Tags: antlr

I have realy simple DSL defined in ANTLR like this.

```
grammar Transformer;
fragment  Digit : [0-9];
Amp:'\'';
Left:'(';
Right: ')';
Comma: ',';
Id: [A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9]+;
Int: '-'? Digit+;
WS: [\n\r\t]+ ->skip;

FuncStart: '>';
DataStart: '#';


parse: (datainput | function)+;
qoutedtext: Amp .*? Amp;
datainput: DataStart Id;
function: FuncStart Id Left param (Comma param)* Right;
param: (datainput|function|qoutedtext|Int);
```

When parsing this text

```
#Id;>ToUpper(#Name);ThisShouldEndUpAsAToken>FillLeft(#EmpNo,20,'abc')
```

This is the "tree" i get:
[image]

The tree looks as expecte, except that I am not able to catch the ThisShouldEndUpAsAToken tekst as a token. 
I know that I do not have any parse in the grammer that should do that now, but I'm not able to figure out how to do it.

HEEELP :)

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your `parse` rule like this:

`parse: (datainput | function | Id)+;`

(Your test input is sprinkled with `;` that shouldn't parse. Are you sure that's the input you're parsing?)